# Writing my first API, server not sending any response

Tags: php, rest, httpresponse

I am writing my first api for my mobile app.  The app is initiating a http call to the server, I can see the call going out and I the app is recording a HTTP 200 OK response from the server.  However I am not seeing anything coming back from the server even with the most basic test code:

```
<?php

// Helper method to get a string description for an HTTP status code
function getStatusCodeMessage($status)  {
    $codes = Array(
        ... some basic codes edited down
        200 => 'OK',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        ... // more edited out
    );     
    return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}

// Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message
function sendResponse($status, $body, $content_type = 'text/html') {
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}

var $testB = json_encode(array(
  "testB" => "has worked",
  "apiDataB" => "accepted"
))  ;
sendResponse(200, json_encode($testB));  
// I then changed this to 400 just to see if the app recorded the 400 response 
// but it did not, it still recorded `200 OK`
?>
```

I am expecting to see a JSON Object $testB to come back to the app but though the app is recording:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 21:23:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

The Preview/Response components (from within Chrome Inspector) are blank.What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you calling the API?

Comment: it shouldn't matter, but if you're sending JSON it should be `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: You double-`json_encode` your `$testB`. Maybe this causes any issues?!

Comment: @Andreas That won't cause an empty response, it will just cause a double-encoded response.

Comment: Check your server log to see if you're getting "Headers already sent" warning.

Comment: @Barmar your'e absolutely right. And I've missed the default `text/html` Content Type totally ;) Nevertheless i think this double-encoding is unnecessary.

Comment: To declare the end of the Header there muss be a CRLF and an empty line before The Message Body Starts : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4

Comment: `var $foo = 'bar';` in Php is a syntax error if it's outside a class.  Remove the `var` before `$testB`.

Comment: @Progrock - you win the award for today!  It was the 'var' issue...originally I did have it inside a class but when things were working I removed most stuff to make it very basic.  @Andreas - Though for better formatting, you are right, it shold be application/json - however, when leaving the response Content-Type: text/html I was still able to get the correct data returned to the app.  My response is coming back as: `"{\"testB\":\"has worked\",\"apiDataB\":\"accepted\"}"` no matter which content-type I use....must be a json_encode issue.

Comment: ...when things "weren't" working...

Comment: ...and lastly, I was using a double json_encode...removed one of them and my app is getting a proper json now.  Cool.  Thanks everyone.  Now its time to go make the donuts!